# Сложноподчиненное предложение

Tags: синтаксис, части-речи

*Так протекала мирная жизнь человека, который с четырьмястами жалованья умел быть довольным своим жребием, и дотекла, может быть, до глубокой старости, если бы не было разных бедствий, рассыпанных на жизненной дороге не только титулярным, но даже тайным, действительным, наддворным и всяким советникам, даже и тем, которые не дают никому советов, ни от кого не берут их сами.*

1. Скажите, пожалуйста, присоединительная конструкция — "и дотекла... до глубокой старости" — рассматривается как отдельная главная часть или входит в состав главной части — "так протекала мирная жизнь человека"?
2. "Даже и тем" — это присоединительная конструкция?
3. Какой частью речи будет выступать слово "сами" — местоимением или наречием?
4. Какие здесь наблюдаются виды подчинения?

Comment: "... тем, которые ..." Тут рассогласование множественного и единственного числа. Не ошибка ли?

Comment: Это цитата из повести Н. В. Гоголя "Шинель".

Comment: Смотрите, вот так правильно:
Рассыпанных (кому) тем, которые не дают никому советов.
А вот так нет:
Рассыпанных (кем) тем, которые не дают никому советов.

Пока похоже на ошибку, и пусть меня кто-нибудь переубедит.

Comment: @user, вы приводите два абсолютно одинаковых примера с разными вопросами. Почему первый правильный, второй -- нет?

Comment: Потому что одно и то же предложение корректно для выражения одного смысла и некорректно для выражения другого. Но какой смысл хотел выразить Гоголь? Ясно что второй, "рассыпанных кем". Но грамматика пытается убедить нас что он хотел выразить первый смысл "рассыпанных кому". Такое возможно, но этот довольно корявый смысл: советник рассыпал бедствия для всех даже для тех кто никогда не советует. Вместо: и советующий и даже никогда несоветующий советники рассыпали бедствия для всех.

Comment: @user190920 Странный смысл Вы вкладываете в это предложение. Бедствия рассыпает, скажем так, судьба, а не советники, и рассыпает она их, конечно, [кому] советникам. А как-раз в Вашей интерпретации грамматика была бы неверной (должно было бы быть "рассыпанных [кем] **теми**").

Comment: В моей интерпретации (рассыпанных [кем]) грамматика не верна, я и пишу об этом, смотрите внимательнее выше (я бы процитировал будь мы на dxd :) ). Насчет смысла: Гоголь сначала говорит что бедствия рассыпал тайный советник, затем еще какой-то. Тут вроде нет разночтений. Потом вдруг говорит что он рассыпал их для кого-то, для тех кто не дает советов. Так что аргумент с судьбой не в кассу (ведь в этом же предложении советники уже рассыпают один раз бедствия, а второй раз оказывается их рассыпает судьба?? )

PS. Смотрите Людмила тоже поправила ошибку в предложении (советникОм на советникАм)!

Comment: То есть, исходное предложение было написано с ошибкой, что я и утверждал с самого начала. А как её править вопрос другой. Можно поправить "тем" на "теми" (как предлагал я) можно "советником" на "советникам" (как в оригинале).

Comment: @user, я понял вашу мысль. Согласен, что предложение некорректно. Но не согласен, что Гоголь хотел выразить второй смысл: рассыпанных кем.

Comment: Ребята, я просто посмотрела, как у Гоголя - там "советникАм", кстати, в других заданиях по данному тексту тоже -А-, просто опечатка, да и смысл присоединения : "всяким советникАм, даже и тем (кому, каким советникам)"

Comment: @Людмила, согласен с вами.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Так протекала мирная жизнь человека], (который с четырьмястами жалованья умел быть довольным своим жребием), и [дотекла бы, может быть, до глубокой старости],
(если бы не было разных бедствий, рассыпанных на жизненной дороге не только титулярным, но даже тайным, действительным, надворным и всяким советник**А**м, даже и тем), (которые не дают никому советов, ни от кого не берут их сами)

1) Это переходный случай, одни учёные утверждают, что предложение ***Так протекала мирная жизнь человека,... и дотекла бы, может быть, до глубокой старости*** простое с однородными членами, другие видят присоединительную конструкцию, а третьи усматривают сложное предложение, где второе простое неполное с пропуском местоимения ОНА, потому что одно сказуемое несовершенного вида, второе совершенного, что говорит о ситуациях, происходящих в разное время.

Я считаю верным последнее утверждение — это отдельное неполное предложение, потому что однородные члены отвечают на одинаковые вопросы, а здесь разные (что делала? и что сделала?).

2) "Даже и тем" — это присоединительная конструкция?

Да, присоедительный член предложения - определение к дополнению  **советникам**

3) Какой частью речи будет выступать слово "сами" — местоимением или наречием?

Часть речи — определительное местоимение.

4) Какие здесь наблюдаются виды подчинения?

Если Вы приняли мнение, что главных два предложения, то первое СПП с одним придаточным, а второе СПП с двумя придаточными, соединёнными последовательным подчинением.

Если скажете, что всё это одно СПП с 3 придаточными, то виды подчинения — параллельное и последовательное.

Comment: Почему "советникАм"?

Comment: @Людмила, а если усматривать здесь присоединительную конструкцию, как ее рассматривать - как главное предложение?

Comment: @Артем Луговой, ср:  рассыпанных (кому?) советникАм, и даже тем (кому?) которые не дают никому советов...  рассыпанных (кем?) советникОм и даже тем (кому?), которые не дают никому советов...  Т. е. здесь два зависимых слова от одного глагола, но при этом у них разное управление.

Comment: @Серж: а-а, понятно! Я просто привык, что обычно так выделяют ударную гласную.

Comment: Серж, Вы о "даже и тем" ?— это  присоедительный член предложения , к которому относится придаточное предложение. Присоединительная конструкция может быть предложением, а может быть отдельным членом предложения. Здесь член предложения - определение.

Comment: @Людмила, нет. Я о первом предложении: и дотекла бы, может быть...

Comment: @Серж, но если признать, что это отдельное предложение, то конечно, именно к нему как главному и относится придаточное (если ...). Я не знаю, что за тема у автора вопроса, но если он признаёт эту часть за присоединительную конструкцию, то это уже не однородные сказуемые, а добавочное высказывание, а значит, отдельное предложение с пропущенным подлежащим. Нужно выбирать - или однородные члены, или присоединение.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за исчерпывающий ответ!